# packaging/patch org on newer version than subscriber orgs: how to patch?

Tags: managed-package, isv

Every time Salesforce rolls out a seasonal update we face the following problem:

- our packaging org as well as all patch orgs linked to it are on a node that is in the first tranche of orgs being upgraded (at the day of writing this, they already run on API 46, Summer 19)
- many of our subscriber orgs are in the second tranche, ie they are still on 45 (Spring 19)
- we are unable to roll out a package/patch to those subscriber orgs until they are upgraded to 46 one week after our packaging/patch orgs have been upgraded

Any thoughts/hints on how to deal with this "deadlock" which we face in 3 weeks per year? My only idea is to ask Salesforce to move our packaging org to a node that lives in the "second tranche", however this seems like a long shot. Another hope is that 2nd gen packaging will solve this issue for good, but this is an even longer shot :)

looking forward to hear your thoughts